# How to inject a SyncAdapter

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2, android-syncadapter

I just started to learn how to use Dagger, and I have converted my `Backend` connection class to be injected automatically.

That class handles Retrofit and performs network requests. It used to have static methods but now it is an object, e.g.:

```
Backend.fetchPost(context, 42); // old way
mBackend.fetchPost(42); // mBackend is an injected field
```

The context is used to retrieve the `AccountManager` which provides the OAuth token with my backend server. This is now injected automatically.

That works well in activities and fragments but I can't figure out how to inject my `SyncAdapter` class.
Indeed, it is a framework object that I don't have control over, and `AndroidInjections` doesn't have a static method ready to inject that kind of class.

Here's the code that I would like to get to work:

```
/**
 * Handle the transfer of data between the backend and the app, using the Android sync adapter framework.
 */
public class SyncAdapter extends AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter {    
    @Inject
    public Backend mBackend; // can't use constructor injection,
                             // so might aswell use a public field

    public SyncAdapter(Context context, boolean autoInitialize) {
        super(context, autoInitialize);
    }

    public SyncAdapter(Context context, boolean autoInitialize, boolean allowParallelSyncs) {
        super(context, autoInitialize, allowParallelSyncs);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPerformSync(Account account, Bundle extras, String authority, ContentProviderClient provider, SyncResult syncResult) {
        List<Post> posts = mBackend.getPosts();
        // do stuf with the posts
    }
}
```

So I know I should call `@#!.inject(this)` somewhere in the constructor, but I don't know exactly how I'm supposed to do this:

- use a static field on the application class to retrieve the head of the dependency graph, and let it browse it until it can inject all the fields
- create a factory class and interfaces like the one used for activities and fragments
- something else?

More details about my dagger2 implementation:

- the `Backend` class has an `@Inject` constructor, so dagger should be able to construct it provided it can get instances of the API and the Gson parser:

  ```
  @Inject
  public Backend(BackendApi api, @UploadGson Gson uploadGson) {
      mApi = api;
      mUploadGson = uploadGson;
  }
  ```
- the `BackendModule` dagger module has `@Provide` methods for a `@UploadGson Gson` object, and the dependency list from a `BackendApi` (retrofit) to the application class (through various objects such as injectors or loggers)
- the `BackendModule.class` is referenced in the `modules = {}` declaration of the application `@Component`

So basically, given an application object, dagger should be able to instantiate an object of the class `Backend`, which I want to inject into my `SyncAdapter` class.
I just don't know how to actually trigger the injection.

PS: as stated, I learned Dagger yesterday, so please advise if you think that my implementation is broken.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think I went too fast posting here. I thought the framework instantiated my `SyncAdapter`, however I'm doing it myself:

```
public class SyncService extends Service {
    private static final Object sSyncAdapterLock = new Object();

    private static SyncAdapter sSyncAdapter = null;

    /**
     * Instantiate the sync adapter object.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        synchronized (sSyncAdapterLock) {
            if (sSyncAdapter == null) {
                sSyncAdapter = new SyncAdapter(getApplicationContext(), true); // bingo!
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Return an object that allows the system to invoke the sync adapter.
     */
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return sSyncAdapter.getSyncAdapterBinder();
    }
}
```

So I just need to inject the service and I'm done. Here's how to fix that:

```
public class SyncService extends Service {
    @Inject
    SyncAdapter sSyncAdapter;

    /**
     * Instantiate the sync adapter object.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        AndroidInjection.inject(this);
    }

    /**
     * Return an object that allows the system to invoke the sync adapter.
     */
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return sSyncAdapter.getSyncAdapterBinder();
    }
}
```

Here's the sync adapter: the default constructor was hidden (made private) and the new constructor is crafted for Dagger: it expects directly `SyncService` as a context and injects the backend and other objects (in my case, a repository class).

```
public class SyncAdapter extends AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter {
    private static final String TAG = SyncAdapter.class.getSimpleName();

    private Backend mBackend;

    private PostRepository mRepository;

    @Inject
    SyncAdapter(SyncService service, Backend backend, PostRepository repo) {
        this(service, true);
        mBackend = backend;
        mRepository = repo;
    }

    private SyncAdapter(Context context, boolean autoInitialize) {
        super(context, autoInitialize);
    }
```

New subcomponent for Service injection:

```
@Subcomponent(modules = {})
public interface SyncServiceSubcomponent extends AndroidInjector<SyncService> {
    @Subcomponent.Builder
    abstract class Builder extends AndroidInjector.Builder<SyncService> {
    }
}
```

Here's the module that references that subcomponent. It provides the `SyncService` (and `AuthenticatorService`, which is implemented in the exact same behavior) expected by the `SyncAdapter` constructor (resp. `Authenticator`):

```
/**
 * Used to provide/bind services with a factory
 * Services can't be injected in the constructor so this is required
 */
@Module(subcomponents = {
        SyncServiceSubcomponent.class,
        AuthenticatorServiceSubcomponent.class,
})
public abstract class ServicesModule {
    @Binds
    @IntoMap
    @ServiceKey(SyncService.class)
    abstract AndroidInjector.Factory<? extends Service> bindSyncServiceInjectorFactory(SyncServiceSubcomponent.Builder builder);

    @Binds
    @IntoMap
    @ServiceKey(AuthenticatorService.class)
    abstract AndroidInjector.Factory<? extends Service> bindAuthenticatorServiceInjectorFactory(AuthenticatorServiceSubcomponent.Builder builder);
}
```

So the sync adapter has the following dependencies:

- sync service: provided by the `ServicesModule`
- backend, repository, etc: app logic
- service injection: subcomponent

Maybe this can help someone.